# Boost variate_generator for poisson distribution problems

Tags: boost, distribution, poisson

I use boost variate_generator to generate random numbers from poisson distribution for boost_1_46_1 (apparently folder structures for variate_generator randomly change between versions).

The snippets of code are below followed by the error report: apparently it doesn’t recognise a call to `variate_generator` and complains about `variate_generator.hpp:123: error: no type named result_type in class boost::math::poisson_distribution`.

I couldn’t figure out what I am doing wrong – a help would be most appreciated! Thanks.

**code**

```
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp>
using namespace boost;

double  poiss(double mean) {
static boost::mt19937 randgen(0);
static boost::math::poisson_distribution <double> pd(mean);
    static boost::variate_generator <boost::mt19937&, boost::math::poisson_distribution <double> > generator(randgen, pd); <- line CnvSeg.c:46
return (double) generator();
}
```

**errors**

```
CnvSeg.c:47: error: no match for call to â(boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::math::poisson_distribution<double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> > >) ()â
/home/craczy/boost_1_46_1/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp: In constructor âboost::variate_generator<Engine, Distribution>::variate_generator(Engine, Distribution) [with Engine = boost::mt19937&, Distribution = boost::math::poisson_distribution<double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> >]â:
CnvSeg.c:46:   instantiated from here
/home/craczy/boost_1_46_1/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp:134: error: using invalid field âboost::variate_generator<Engine, Distribution>::_engâ
/home/craczy/boost_1_46_1/include/boost/random/variate_generator.hpp:123: error: no type named âresult_typeâ in âclass boost::math::poisson_distribution<double, boost::math::policies::policy<boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy, boost::math::policies::default_policy> >â
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong Poisson distribution. boost::math distributions don't seem to work with Boost.Random, so use:

```
 #include <boost/random/poisson_distribution.hpp>
 boost::poisson_distribution<> pd(mean);
 boost::variate_generator <boost::mt19937, boost::poisson_distribution<> >
```